# Verifying Newton's 2nd Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

**Background/Experiment setup**: In one of my classes a mass (0.04 kg) was hung from a pulley and attached to a much heavier mass (around 0.4 kg) that rest on an airtrack. A thread connected the hanging mass with the one on the track.

The hanging mass would be dropped and the acceleration of the mass on the airtrack would be calculated. For 5 trials the mass was increased .01 kg and the acceleration calculated.

Then I divided gravity by each calculated acceleration so I ended up with 6 new numbers. Then for each mass I divided $m_1$ ($0.4$      kg) by each hanging mass. Then I plotted $\frac{m_1}{m_2}$ as the $x$ axis of a graph and $\frac ga$ as the $y$ axis.

Then I found a line of best fit:
 $y = 1.0004x + 0.99 $

$r^2 = 0.9994. $

So it produces a very straight line, the data line up very well and produce a great line of best fit.

**Question**: How does this verify Newton's 2nd law? I understand that it is $F=ma$, and the graph does show that as mass increases so does acceleration proportionally. IS all that is needed to verify it? I'm having a hard time in my lab write up actually explaining how this set up verifies Newton's 2nd law.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how your equation implies Newton's 2nd law holds.

The equation you discovered looks to me like $$\frac{g}{a}=\frac{m_1}{m_2}+1.$$ This equation can be re-arranged and written: $$m_2g=(m_1+m_2)a.$$
The left-hand side is the magnitude of the gravitational force acting on the smaller hanging mass $m_2$. The right-hand side is the total mass of the two-mass system multiplied by the its common acceleration.

Hopefully that is enough for you to see that what you discovered is Newton's 2nd law. Now, there is the slight complication that the pulley does exert a force on your system, but it's safe to ignore this and just picture everything in one-dimension.

Answer (score 1):

> IS all that is needed to verify it?

Yes. Newton's second law $\Leftrightarrow$ Force is proportional to mass with the acceleration being the constant of proportionality.

Since it's a straight line, this implies proportionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I understand how the mass is the constant, as the hanging weight changes each test, only the weight on the track is constant.

Comment: @WaywardEevee: Right, it's the acceleration which is constant.  The acceleration is essentially the acceleration due to gravity.